# Windows IoT: Deployment on RaspberryPi 2 gets ignored

Tags: windows-iot, c#

I originally asked my question on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795725/windows-iot-deployment-on-raspberrypi2-gets-ignored but was directed to this beautiful page:

I installed an Windows 10 IoT on my RaspberryPi2 and also all the Visual Studio 2015 stuff I need to get going.
Everything works, if I debug from my VS, but as soon as I deploy, nothing happens: The Raspberry Pi2 doesn't start automatically and I also don't see any special options on the GUI.

My VS output is like this:

> 1>------ Deploy started: Project: BlinkyWebService, Configuration:
>   Release ARM ------ 1>Creating a new clean layout... 1>Copying files:
>   Total <1 mb to layout... 1>Checking whether required frameworks are
>   installed... 1>Registering the application to run from layout...
>   1>Deployment complete (10237ms). Full package name:
>   "BlinkyWebService_1.0.0.0_arm__1w720vyc4ccym" ========== Build: 0
>   succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

The C#-deployment is described here: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/AppDeployment.htm , but only the last point seems relevant here:

> Having successfully deployed and debugged your UWP application, create
>   a Release version by simply changing the Visual Studio toolbar
>   configuration dropdown from Debug to Release. You can now build and
>   deploy your app to your device by selecting Build | Rebuild Solution
>   and Build | Deploy Solution.

Unfortunately, it doesn't give much more informations than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a remote PowerShell session and add the application to the start list.  Have a look at this thread for headless apps:  [questions/34834/failed-to-start-package-window10-iot/36284](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34834/failed-to-start-package-window10-iot/36284)

If it is headed you should be able to select and run the package from the web gui (access via the core watcher utility).

Comment: Many thanks, I now created it with a empty UI (which is called headed then?) and used the following Link. https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/windows-10-iot-core-setting-startup-app-887ed0 I will check back your Answer, but I'm certain, it's the solution.